# How to define two player model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having trouble defining models for two player in django. I somehow managed to define models like this.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Player(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    score = models.IntegerField(default = 0) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Match(models.Model):
    player_one = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player_one')
    player_two = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player_two')

class Score_log(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    log_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-match","-log_time"]
```

In Match model, `player_one` and `player_two` is defined because i want to validate those with django forms.
Also, I am unable to retrieve my objects with `Match.player_one.all()` and says `'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`.Help_me_out?

Comment: tried `Match.objects.player_one.all()` but says `'Manager' object has no attribute 'player_one'`

Comment: what are you getting at `Match.objects.all()` ?

Comment: I'm getting `'Match' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: `Match.objects.all()` should produce a querylist are you sure you are getting `'Match' object has no attribute 'name'` ?

Comment: yeah, im sure..`Match` model have two foreignkey coming from same parent `Player`. is it still possible to do `Match.objects.all()` ?

Comment: FYI, please remove either `__unicode__` or `__str__` entirely. If you're using python 2 remove `__str__`. If you're using python 3 remove `__unicode__`.

Comment: Yea its possible to do `Match.objects.all()` doing this you can access both `player_one` and `player_two data`

Comment: Now i managed to get `Match.objects.all()`  getting `<QuerySet [<Match: Match object>]>` but i am not able to get player_one and player_two data

Comment: and whats the output `Match.objects.all()[0]`

Comment: now `Match,objects.all()[0]` returned me `Match object` after that i tried to get player instance with `Matc.objects.all()[0].player_one` and `Match.objects.all()[0].player_two` and it worked out..Thank you!! [Bijoy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5919344/bijoy)